# Limited or no connectivity on windows clients

Tags: server, dhcp

here's my scenario

Using ubuntu server non gui, I would set up a server with static IP on eth0 then share the connection on eth1 -> connected to a network switch.

i did set up eth0 as static, installed isc-dhcp-server, set up ip and range, set eth1 as default interface for dhcp server, started dhcp server, connected the client pc to the switch, but cant access the internet

do i still have to set up eth1 ip on /etc/network/interfaces?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable ip_forward and configure MASQUERADING with iptables in such a way that your internal network can route traffic to the internet via the external interface of your firewall if I understand your question correctly.